# typo3 7.6.9 connection problems

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Hi together I've updated my typo3 7.6.4 to 7.6.9

Just switched the symlink of typo3_src

Now I got this error in backend

[image]

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say its the cache... did you try to clear all cache in the install tool ?

Then you could clear all content of the directory typo3temp, and then clear the cache in your admin panel ...

Comment: ps: you should do the 'complete clean-up' from the install tool before trying anything else, just follow the menu and see what can be cleared/emptied ...

Comment: still have the problem ? I work locally with xampp, I sometimes restart the server but as a matter of fact I do not have symlinks ...

Comment: just checked it again .. and now there are no problems anymore ... mysterious ... but okay :P 

Thanks